# Access Running service and call its method?

Tags: android, background-service

I've created a service that sends location in back ground now

> i want to create a **method** in my **ACTIVITY** which will access the
>   currently running instance of service and will call its method

Say Location Service having Methode

```
SendLocation()
{
/// to do 
}
```

Now in Activity A:

> **Service s = getCurrentRunningServiceInstance // something like this**

and call its method

```
s.SendLocation();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't call a method on a `Service` directly. What you need to do is `bind` to the `Service`.

In your `Service`, override `onBind()` and have it return a valid `IBinder` then use this in a client/server fashion.

See the docs for [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) particularly with respect to [Creating a Bound Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingBoundService) and also the docs for [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

Answer (score 1):

Method calling of service is not recommended, Instead of this, follow below steps

1) create an BroadcastReciever in Activity.

2) from service when location changed, send a broadcast intent with location extras,

3) listen it from Receiver in Activity and update activiy accordingly.

Comment: hi,it's possible to call method of any running service?